# Slow Driving an Air Compressor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, compressed-air, compressors

Do off-the-shelf air compressors have minimum driving speeds, below which they cannot build the necessary pressure? Reciprocating compressors and scroll compressors are available—is there a difference in minimum working speed?

In my application, I would like to drive a compressor at very slow speeds (1–10 rpm) to store wind energy over a long period of time, but I'm concerned internal leakage inside the compressor may make that nonviable.

Comment: I suggest you explain a little more about what you want to do.  I gather so far that you want to use a windmill to power an air compressor and perhaps use the compressed air as a power source.  If that's the case, it will be important to choose the right kind of air compressor, which come in a variety of different designs, each best suitable for different applications.  I don't think your question has an answer unless you specify the kind of compressor at hand.

Comment: @ttonon That's correct, I want to use a small windmill (of the type used for water pumping) to power an air compressor, using the compressed air as an energy storage medium. I do not have a compressor yet. Although it might not be clear, the question is attempting to ask whether there is any compressor on the market that would meet the stated requirement, to be able to be driven slowly by a small power source. A smaller compressor driven faster might be an acceptable option, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google dugout aeration windmill system.

There are various makers.  Here's one:  https://koenderswatersolutions.ca/

The compressor on them does one cycle per revolution of the windmill.  While not as slow as 1 rpm the one I have is only rarely over 50 rpm.

Internally they are a diaphragm pump. This means you only have the leaking of the valves to contend with.

The unit I have is fairly low pressure.  The pond is 14 feet deep, so the pressure is only about 7 PSI plus friction losses in the 1000 feet of 5/8 tubing between the windmill and the pond.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: I see there is at least one maker that can generate up to 15 cfm at 175 psi! That's substantial. http://windcompressor.com/html/compressors.html